# How to set the PATH environment variable

Tags: php, apache

In the [Apache 2.2 doc](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_env.html#setenv) it says:

> On 2.2, the PATH environment variable cannot be set using Setenv.

Right. I now need to add another directory to the path environment variable that actually is:

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

This because I need to run with the `shell_exec()` function a command that is installed in:

```
/usr/local/bin/exiftool
```

I'd like to avoid making a link on `/usr/bin` or whatever.